# динамическое программирование

Tags: python, алгоритм

Нужно найти минимальное число `k`, для которого число `w` можно представить как сумму `k` чисел из набора `{v1,…,vn}`. Каждое число из набора можно использовать сколько угодно раз. Известно, что в наборе есть единица и что для любой пары чисел из набора одно из них делится на другое.

```
def dpMakeSum(numValueList, num, minNums, numUsed):
    for n in range(num + 1):
        numCount = n
        newNum = 1
        for j in [c for c in numValueList if c <= n]:
            if minNums[n - j] + 1 < numCount:
                numCount = minNums[n - j] + 1
                newNum = j
        minNums[n] = numCount
        numUsed[n] = newNum
    return minNums[num]

    def printNum(numUsed, value):
    res = ''
    v = value
    while v > 0:
        thisNum = numUsed[v]
        res += str(thisNum) + ' '
        v = v - thisNum
    return res

    def main():
    results = input().split(' ')
    results = [int(i) for i in results]
    value = results[1]
    num_array = sorted(results[2:])    
    numUsed = [0] * (value + 1)
    numCount = [0] * (value + 1)

    print(str((dpMakeSum(num_array, value, numCount, numUsed)))+' '+(printNum(numUsed, value)))
    main()
```

на тестовых данных вываливается на:

```
Failed test #15. Run time error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "jailed_code", line 36, in <module>
    main()
  File "jailed_code", line 30, in main
    numUsed = [0] * (value + 1)
MemoryError
```

Как можно заоптимизировать?

**Обновление**

```
def solve_sum(num_array, value):
    dividers = [i for i in num_array if i <= value]
    dividers = sorted(dividers, reverse=True)
    res = []
    n = 0
    while value:
        res += [dividers[n]] * (value // dividers[n])
        k = (value // dividers[n])
        value %= dividers[n]
        n += k
    return str(n)+' '+" ".join(map(str, res))


results = input().split(' ')
results = [int(i) for i in results]
value = results[1]
num_array = results[2:]

print(solve_sum(num_array, value))
```

Теперь не попадаю в лимит 3 сек.

Comment: Полностью менять алгоритм, разумеется. «Заоптимизировать» принесёт вам ну 30 процентов ускорения.

Comment: Найдите дубликат, кто-нибудь?

Comment: на какой алгоритм менять?

Comment: @VladD - http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/472427

Comment: @Igor: о, спасибо!